# PyMongo aggregation group by year and date yielding wrong results

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

There is product data in my MongoDB, just like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c768a392a0dc85b24602575"),
    "sku" : "123456",
    "brand" : "Test Brand",
    "url" : "https://www.example.com/product1.html",
    "time" : ISODate("2019-09-27T08:01:45.892Z")
}
```

That is the Python / PyMongo code that I'm using:

```
start = datetime(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0)

cursor = collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            '$match': 
            {
                'time': 
                {
                    '$gte': start
                },
                'brand':
                {
                    '$ne' : None
                }
            }
        },

        {
            '$project': 
            {
                '_id'   : 1,
                'sku'   : 1,
                'brand' : 1,
                'url'   : 1,
                'time'  : 1
            }
        },

        {
            '$group':
            {
                '_id'   : '$url',
                'sku'   : {'$first':'$sku'},
                'brand' : {'$first':'$brand'},
                'time'  : {'$first':'$time'}
            }
        },

        {
            '$project': 
            {
                'year'  : {'$year' :  "$time"},
                'month' : {'$month' :  "$time"},
                'brand' : 1
            }
        },


        {
            "$group":
            {
                "_id"   : {'year' : "$year", 'month' : "$month"},
                'count' : { '$sum': 1 }
            }
        },

        # Need to add sth here or change the last group stage to "count" the brands

        {
            '$sort':
            {
                '_id'   : 1
            }
        }

    ]
)




for row in cursor:
    print ( row )
```

Then I change this variable and run the program several times:

```
start = datetime(2019, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0)
start = datetime(2019, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0)
start = datetime(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

and the output is:

```
$ python products_per_brand.py 
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 9}, 'count': 96747}
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 10}, 'count': 13051}
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 11}, 'count': 12069}
$ python products_per_brand.py 
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 8}, 'count': 93315}
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 9}, 'count': 25266}
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 10}, 'count': 12339}
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 11}, 'count': 11632}
$ python products_per_brand.py 
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 7}, 'count': 93085}
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 8}, 'count': 10517}
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 9}, 'count': 24559}
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 10}, 'count': 12170}
{'_id': {'year': 2019, 'month': 11}, 'count': 11463}
```

Questions:

1. How to show the amount of products per brand per month?
2. Why are the results different per month? (main question)

(The data hasn't been changed)

Comment: Conclusively answering the 2nd question would require access to the entire data set. However, I strongly suspect that the changing results per month is due to the usage of `$first` in the first `$group` stage, where you group by `url`. The result of `$first` is only meaningful when used in a defined order. This aggregation doesn't specify a sort, so the result wouldn't be meaningful.

Comment: Perfect guess - the $first for time doesn't make sense of course. I'll have to re-do this part of the aggregation.